# Errors upon Injecting $urlRouterProvider into a directive

Tags: angularjs

Angular is throwing an "Unknown Provider" error when I am injecting $urlRouterProvider into my directive. Although there is no error when i inject $state. Not able to figure this out.

Replicated the same in a plnkr below
http://plnkr.co/edit/sK0NYNDRtH4lFfteNd5O

Answer (score 0):

Used an alternate approach

$window.location.href

For now issue resolved